Rails form with custom name not sending correct param to controller
I have a survey form in Rails that loops through questions in a database table and generates a group of radio buttons (answer choices) for each question.
Each group of radio buttons is supposed to have a different name value, and the submission creates a new record in the Answers table for each answer.
However, I'm getting ParameterMissing errors because the form sends:
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]","answer_value_0"=>"1", "commit"=>"SAVE"}
instead of:
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "answer"=>{"answer_choice"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"SAVE"}
The form looks like:
<%= form_with model: @answers, url: answers_path do |ans|%>

    <% @questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
         <div>
            <%= ans.radio_button :answer_choice, 1,  name: "answer_value_#{index}"%>
            <%= ans.label :answer_value_1, "Yes" %>
        </div>
     
    <%end%>
    <%= ans.submit "SAVE" %>
<%end%>

The controller is called SurveyResultsController and looks like:
def show
    @answers = Answer.new
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

    @questions = @survey.questions
  
end

def create
    @survey = Survey.find_by(params[:id])
    
    @answers = Answer.new(answer_params)
      
    if @answers.save
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        redirect_to show_survey_path(@survey)
    end
    
end

def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:answer_choice)
end


@answers = Answer.new(answer_params), @answers = Answer.new — why plural here? It is strange enough

You really don't need/want to reinvent the nested form wheel. First fix your models and then use nested attributes and fields_for. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

The name Answer here is kind of wierd/confusing as it kind of implies the answer to a single question. Using the wrong pluralization makes it even more confusing. I would call it SurveyReply or something less ambigous and give it a has_many :user_answers.

Change name of the field from "answer_value_#{index}" to "[answer]answer_value_#{index}". It will wrap params with answer key
Or it's better to change :model key (pass single @answer = Answer.new from the controller) and modify your form
<%= form_with model: @answer, url: answers_path do |form|%>
  <% @questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
    <div>
      <%= form.radio_button :answer_choice, some_value, id: "answer_choice_#{index}" %>
      <%= form.label "choice_#{index}", some_label %>
    </div>
     
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "SAVE" %>
<% end %>

This form render radiobuttons with labels (you need specify some_label somehow). And it will send params (if some_value is one of 0 or 1) in such manner:
"answer"=>{"answer_choice"=>"1"}

or
"answer"=>{"answer_choice"=>"0"}


Thanks, but this still give a ParameterMissing error and is returning:  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "[answer]answer_value_0"=>"1", "commit"=>"SAVE"}

The first option still gives error. Second option: I actually am processing values that are different than the index, so I have to be able to specify the value as 0 or 1 and text labels. This method makes the value and the label the index
